# Custom Seekbar class implenting OnSeekBarChangeListener, onProgressChanged never called

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have a custom Seekbar class that has implemented OnSeekBarChangeListener, but the method `onProgressChanged` is never called and I am unsure why.

```
public class SeekbarSphereNodeRotator extends AppCompatSeekBar implements AppCompatSeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SeekbarSphereNodeRotato";

   
    public SeekbarSphereNodeRotator(Context context) {
        super(context);
        //Gets called
        Log.d(TAG, "SeekbarSphereNodeRotator: " + mCurrentRotatedAngle);
    }

    public SeekbarSphereNodeRotator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SeekbarSphereNodeRotator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        //Never called
        Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged: " + progress);
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
}
```

The constructor is called, but the method `onProgressChanged` never is when I'm moving the seekbar thumb. What am I doing incorrectly?

`mSeekbarImageRotater = new SeekbarSphereNodeRotator(MainActivity.this);`

**Edit:**

I've tried adding `setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);` in the constructor but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set

`setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);`

in

```
public SeekbarSphereNodeRotator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   uper(context, attrs);
}
```

for the listener to work.